# F3 Sql Mapper: Misleading error message when setting value for non existent field in the mapped table

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Given this code

```php
$mapper->reset();
$mapper->set( 'foo', 'bar' ); // <--- Error here: `foo` does not exists in the table
$mapper->insert();
```

Where `foo` is a column that does **not** esist in the mapped table I get this error

```
Internal Server Error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
1054 Unknown column 'bar' in 'field list' 
[/var/www/example.com/html/lib/php/fatfreeframework/DB/SQL.php:230]
```

The error message is misleading in fact the non existent column is `foo`, **not** `bar`: the latter is the value that has been attempted to set to the non-existent column.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix this?

-

Php 8.1.9

pdo_mysql Client API version => mysqlnd 8.1.9

mysql 8.0.30

Comment: Well if your investigation turned out that the error message is wrong, this might be a pointer that there could be a flaw in that library. Investigate further by automating the test and debug then within the automation. This could lead to a way to fix this (e.g. by writing a patch and then filing it upstream). Alternatively you can also test against different revisions of the library to find out when this behaviour has changed (e.g. with [git binary search](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)). Btw. which version are you using? And adding the PHP version you're running doesn't hurt either.

Comment: And thinking: From the error message it looks to me it is from the database server. So this looks that the _F3 SQL Mapper_ is only passing the error _from_ the database server along. So you should also [edit] in which database server you're using (and its version).

Comment: @hakre `it looks to me it is from the database server` I totally agree. Still, I think something should be done to fix this...

Comment: Okay, so could it be then that `set()` works differently than you have in mind? It may require that the first parameter *must* be an existing column name to be the second parameter a value (and not a (column) name). Just thinking loud. And Have you already identified the revision of F3 SQL Mapper that introduced the behaviour you'd like to fix?

Comment: @hakre `And Have you already identified the revision of F3 SQL Mapper` no, before digging into F3 I was hoping to get some insights from the F3 folks. I also opened a issue on the F3 github repo

Comment: Don't hide the link to the issue on GH. And while you may still want to find out if there was a change in the past and don't have the revision it introduced (yet), I think you should add the version of the library to your question regardless. And the "need" alone to fix something, also may not be a good fit on SO, unless it is a concrete programming question (in the sense of dealing with the actual code, with libraries it is making the library code your own, not just using some API, at least in that direction). Linking to the GH issue therefore would be very helpful therefore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By opening a [issue on github](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues/1266) I got the answer from [**@ikkez**](https://github.com/ikkez):

---

This is currently the expected behavior because setting a field not existing = defining an adhoc field.

```
$mapper->set('count_x',
             'SELECT COUNT(id) from x where x.id = y.foreign_key group by x.id');
```

ref.: https://fatfreeframework.com/3.8/databases#VirtualFields

The way to fix this is to apply a whitelist of fillable fields that are allowed to be set in case you are using something like `copyfrom`.

i.e.:

```php
$mapper->copyfrom('POST', function($val) {
    return array_intersect_key($val, array_flip(['first_name', 'last_name', 'age']));
});
```